# ajaxSubmit uploadProgress not responding

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem with the `$(a).AjaxSubmit` of `jQuery.Form`, with respect of option UploadProgress. This is my code:

```
$("#ifrm").contents().find("form").ajaxSubmit({
    data: { " + datos + " },
    target: "#sbmt",
    forceSync: true,
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        alert(percentComplete);
    },
    success: function(html, status) {},
    complete: function(xhr) {
        if (xhr.statusText == "OK") {
            eval(xhr.responseText)
        }
        else {
            msgbox("Error en el Formulario", "Se produjo un error al subir el archivo.", 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

The alert never appears. I need the event for a progress bar.

Comment: Your code doesn't have a URL parameter. Also, add a callback for `error` to see if that gets hit.

Comment: hi! the problem is that not have any problem with the firebug or the chrome and work perfect with this two browser, the problem is IE. I read that the problem recide is that IE not soport response XMLHTTPREQUEST.. In the rest of browser work perfectly..plis I need help with this..Thanks..Mery

Comment: In IE7 and other version is not work because not soport XMLHTTPREQUEST level 2, it work the normal response but not work the upload response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the ajaxForm plugin to the latest version. the problem will be solved.

Plugin URL : http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: I'm using 3.32.0-2013.04.09 same issue.

Comment: updated to 3.33 from the repository... no dice for IE8 or IE9